# How to find the first numbers of IP string netstat?

Tags: findstr, netstat

I would like to know, but cant find the solution.
How i can find IP with netstat that is starting with numbers like 200 only

netstat -ano | findstr 200

Searches from all occurrencies not from the start

Answer (score 1):

Use grep command with regex pattern to filter.

```
netstat -ano | grep -i "UDP\s*200.*"
```